# How to Call Specific .PHP file on add_submenu_page selection in Plugin Development?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page

I want to structure my Plugin folder & file system in a way, where in **add_submenu_page** when I will click on my sub menu link it will call separate .php file where i will car specific function which will do their job.

This is my Code.

```
// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

/* Adding Plugin Menu to WordPress Dashboard */
add_action('admin_menu', 'myfunction_admin_menu');


/** Admin Menu **/
function myfunction_admin_menu()
{
    
  // Double check user capabilities
  if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
      return;
  }
    
    // Adding main menu in administrative area.

    add_menu_page('Digital', 'Menu', 'manage_options', 'myfunction', 'myfunction_settings_page', plugins_url('digisol/assets/images/myfunction.png'), 100 );
    add_submenu_page('myfunction', 'Option 1', 'Option 1', 'manage_options', 'mydifferentfile.php');
    
    }


function myfunction_settings_page()
{
    // Double check user capabilities
    if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
      return;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1><?php esc_html_e( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
      <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Some content.', 'myfunction' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Where my submenu **myfunction** will call **mydifferentfile.php** file from plugin's includes folder.

In that file I want Store Some information (Insert/Update/Delete/Display) Operations in specific table of database.

So How can I implement it.?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just `include mydifferentfile.php` into the `myfunction_settings_page` function?

Comment: Thank you Jacob, Initially your solution helped me to figure our how to call my seperate file on call. then I face one more problem to handle but found the solution on this link - https://tommcfarlin.com/save-wordpress-submenu-page-options/